# Sending gif by ftp to a server in different folders

Tags: perl, ftp

I use perl for sending gif to a server. I want to move some gif to a folder called precipitation and other gifs to a folder called wind. Now with the following code (well, it is a part of the code I use) I send them, but there is something wrong in the code, because I find all gif in the same folder, in the first one, precipitation. Any idea?

```
use BSD::Resource;
use File::Copy;
use Net::FTP;


#ACCIONS  send gif to the folder precipitation
$ftp->cwd("html/pen/precipitation");
foreach my $file ($ftp->ls("Pl*.gif")){
$ftp->delete($file) or die "Error in delete\n";
}
my @arxius = glob("/home/gif/Pen/Pl*.gif");
foreach my $File(@arxius){
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->put("$File");
}

#ACCIONS  send gif to the folder wind
$ftp->cwd("html/pen/wind");
foreach my $file2 ($ftp->ls("vent*.gif")){
$ftp->delete($file2) or die "Error in delete\n";
}
my @arxius2 = glob("/home/gif/Pen/vent*.gif");
foreach my $File(@arxius2){
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->put("$File");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior indicates that the second call to `cwd()` failed.

Most likely this is because you are using a relative rather than absolute path: the second `cwd()` call is relative to the location set in the first one.  It tries to go to `html/pen/precipitation/html/pen/wind` which doesn't appear to be what you want.

Use an absolute path or `../wind` in the second `cwd()` call.

Also, you should check for the success of the `cwd()` commands and stop if you didn't change to the expected directory.  Otherwise, you are performing potentially destructive actions (like deleting files) in the wrong place!`cwd()` will return true if it worked and false otherwise.  See the [`Net::FTP` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html).

Comment: Yes, I know that deleting files by ftp is dangerous but, it is what I can manage now

Comment: @EnricAgudPique, I have no problem with deleting files by FTP when appropriate.  Error checking will just help make the operation safer.